# Change network settings programmatically without root

Tags: linux, networking, c

I want to change network configurations like dhcp, ip address and so on programmatically.

**But** what I don't want, is to run my application as root.
So my question is: What would be a common approach to solve that? Is this even possible?

Is there maybe any group that is allowed to do that without gaining any other rights? Or should I 'chown' the config files to a special group and add the user to that group?

**Related to this** (If that is off topic, tell me and I will open another question):
The target is an embedded device and the application should be the only one that is accessible by the user. Is there any good (best) practice? Should I create a special user for that application. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might set capabilities on your program.  This would allow it to do certain privileged tasks without the need to run completely as `root`.  The capability in question here is `CAP_NET_ADMIN`:

```
CAP_NET_ADMIN
    Perform various network-related operations:
     * interface configuration;
     * administration of IP firewall, masquerading, and accounting;
     * modify routing tables;
     * bind to any address for transparent proxying;
     * set type-of-service (TOS)
     * clear driver statistics;
     * set promiscuous mode;
     * enabling multicasting;
     * use  setsockopt(2)  to set the following socket options: SO_DEBUG, SO_MARK,
       SO_PRIORITY (for a priority outside the range 0 to 6), SO_RCVBUFFORCE,  and
       SO_SNDBUFFORCE.
```

You'll find more information on capabilities in the `capabilities(7)` and `setcap(8)` manpages.

To secure this even more, in case you only need a specific subset of users to be able to run this program, you could put those users into a group, `chgrp` your program into this group and `chmod` it to `0750`.

Comment: That could be interesting to me. Do not have enough reputation to upvote, sorry.

Comment: I am curious about the handling of shared objects. The manual is only talking about threads. So am I right that setting a SO's capability doesn't have any effect on the executed code? As far as I understand the code of the shared object is executed with the capabilities inherited from the thread in which the object is executed in, right?

Comment: I think capabilities only have effect on executables.  Difficult wording, hrm… those things with main() functions. ;)

Comment: So a shared object would inherit capabilitys from the "thing with the main() function" :) ?

Comment: As far as I can see… yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NetworkManager on your computer, you could use [NM-CLI](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/nmcli.1.html).

> nmcli is a command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager and
>   getting
>          its status.  It is not meant as a replacement of nm-applet or other
>          similar clients.  Rather it's a complementary utility to these
>          programs.  The main nmcli's usage is on servers, headless machines or
>          just for power users who prefer the command line.
>
> ```
>    The use cases comprise:
>
>    --  Initscripts: ifup/ifdown can utilize NetworkManager via nmcli
>        instead of having to manage connections itself and possible
>        interfere with NetworkManager.
>
>    --  Servers, headless machines: No GUI is available; then nmcli is used
>        to talk directly to NetworkManager and control only system-wide
>        connections.
>
>    --  User sessions: For this case, nmcli can talk to nm-applet to find
>        user connections.  It can still talk directly to NetworkManager for
>        manipulating these connections.  As nmcli doesn't have direct
>        access to user configuration data in GConf, nm-applet handles that
>        itself.  That may, for example, cause the applet to pop up keyring
>        dialogs when secrets are needed.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If your target device supports it, the setuid-mechanism might be the way to go

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Some programs need root privileges, and what you do with setuid is that the executable file belongs to root and has the setuid-bit set, so when another user executes it, the executable is run with root privileges.

But also note that

> Due to potential security issues, many operating systems ignore the setuid attribute when applied to executable shell scripts.

Comment: Thank you. But I have already thought about setuid and that is not an option for me because I don't want to exec another programm. In that case I could simply use ip or ifconfig with setuid bit set